# How To Check Most Recently Available Mac App Version/Upgrade?

Tags: macos, google-fabric

I just (re)installed the Fabric app for macOS yesterday. This morning I receive a notification that there is a new version of the Fabric app for Mac. My version was 2.6.17. I downloaded Fabric again this morning and its version is ... 2.6.17.

I guess it isn't a big deal reinstalling the same version of the Fabric app every now and again (it takes almost no time), but it would still be nice to know what the current version available for download is prior to actually downloading and installing it. And won't the app itself ask me to update it if it truly needs to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for letting me know. Usually this means the app cache had an issue. It should now be reset, but you can manually do this as well by running:

```
 rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac
```